# Android: Admob Banner with close button above VideoView

Tags: android, android-layout, admob

I wish to make app that will look like YouTube
Video player + banner above video

What layout should I use?

I wish to support android 2.1+ or 2.2+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is code I did:-

```
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams lparams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(40, 40);
                lparams.leftMargin = banner.x;
                lparams.topMargin = banner.y;
                lparams.gravity = Gravity.NO_GRAVITY;
                final ImageButton btn = new ImageButton(activity);
                btn.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_close_clear_cancel);
                btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        btn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        hideAdmob(activity);
                    }
                });
                btn.setLayoutParams(lparams);
                activity.addContentView(btn, lparams);
```